# Enum.reduce/2 doesn't output IO

Tags: elixir

I am working with `Enum.reduce`, and trying to add some debug outputs in the reduce, but it doesn't seem to output it in `Enum.reduce/2`. Works as expected in `Enum.reduce/3`.

```
nodes = [%{"value" => "x"}]

Enum.each(nodes, fn (node) ->
  IO.puts "Each"
  IO.inspect node["value"]
end)

Enum.reduce(nodes, fn (node, acc) ->
  IO.puts "Reduce"
  IO.inspect node["value"]

  [node["value"], acc]
end)

Enum.reduce(nodes, [], fn (node, acc) ->
  IO.puts "Pre-accumulator"
  IO.inspect node["value"]

  [node["value"], acc]
end)
```

When I run it I get the following:

```
Each
"x"
Pre-accumulator
"x"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enum.reduce/2` uses the first value of the enumerable as the initial accumulator. If the enumerable only has one element (like the `nodes` you're using), the function you pass to `reduce/2` is never executed because that first value is the accumulator, and there are no other values left to reduce over.

[The docs for `Enum.reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2) explain it this way:

> Since the first element of the enumerable is used as the initial value of the accumulator, `fun` will only be executed `n - 1` times where `n` is the length of the enumerable. This function won't call the specified function for enumerables that are one-element long.

This makes sense, because using the first value as the initial accumulator and at the same time reducing over it wouldn't make sense as it would be "used" twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense to not reduce it for a single result, just didn't know it would actually not run the reduce function.